# Honoring your Mohel

Tags: brit-milah, kavod, honors

Is it brought down anywhere that one should show honor to the one who circumcised him, since he is the one who brought him into the covenant etc.?

Comment: The mitzva is on the father, not the mohel. Then again, so is ושננתם לבניך.

Comment: What about the doctor that did the delivery, since he brought you into this world?

Comment: And the Kohen who gave you freedom